Why does it show 2 vertices under each other when in edit mode?

So I was making a donut and went In to edit mode and I saw that there was 2 vertices under each other it was really annoying this problem has showed up twice and and it happened with 4 vertices once

This is the effect of your subdivision surface modifier: in orange you have the vertex coordinates location in edit mode, in black the result after the effect of the modifier.
You can change this UI behaviour clicking on the two buttons on the modifier (nothing will change on render, only edit mode UI appearance).

